# Is there any way to to know if the disk is SSD or HDD on a Windows 10 on VM?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, virtual-machine

I think the title is clear enough: Is there any way to to know if the disk is SSD or HDD on a Windows 10 on VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

That is because inside a VM, you cannot see the physical hardware that is backing it. (Except the CPU make and model most of the time.)

You could run benchmarks though to test IOPS and throughput and guess from that.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Great idea, I used a program which calculates the I/O speed and I've determined it's the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what a the VM container pretends the drive is. [this website describes how to check](https://www.top-password.com/blog/find-if-your-drive-is-ssd-or-hdd-in-windows/#:%7E:text=Simply%20press%20the%20Windows%20key,hard%20disk%20drive%20(HDD).)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem with this method is: the disk type is always "unspecified" on a VM.

Comment: @user676767 could you check on the host computer?

Comment: No, because the VM runs on a VPS.

Comment: oh, are you using a cloud service @user676767 often those show what it is running on

Comment: Here is the point, I would like to check if the specs are correct